# clinical report dataset

Tags: data-request, medical, nlp, text

I am doing a research on detecting negation cases on medical reports (NLP medical). 
I need clinical report that contains sentences, patient conditions, patient history, clinical terms, etc
Is anyone can help to find?

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "clinical science reports" (CSR) on Google returns various websites from pharmaceutical companies, which publish summary reports. Maybe these are enough for your research.

As [this article points out](http://www.alltrials.net/news/european-medicines-agency-csr-transparency-policy-0070/) only recently did the European Medicines Agency start publishing CSRs, the Food and Drug administration currently does not.

You can also contact pharmaceutical companies, explain your research proposal and ask for access...